# How to disable image tag when source is empty or undefined or " " or null in Angular4

Tags: html, angular

I am working in an Angular4 application ,In this I am binding image path from API.

In this application I have a HTML page in that when I hover on small images that will display the big size of that image .

What I want to do is When the image path is empty or undefined or null or " " I don't want to display that image .

Currently if the image source is not a valid source it displays the alt tag .But I don't want to disable the alt tag,just disable that whole image section

My HTML

```
<div class="row">
      <img id="sm001" (mouseenter)="mouseEnter($event)"  src="{{smallImages['0']['small_Images']}}" alt="img1" class="img-thumbnail" [attr.ref]="bigImages['0']['big_Images']">
      <img id="sm005" (mouseenter)="mouseEnter($event)"  src="{{smallImages['1']['small_Images']}}" alt="img2" class="img-thumbnail" [attr.ref]="bigImages['1']['big_Images']">
      <img id="sm002" (mouseenter)="mouseEnter($event)"  src="{{smallImages['2']['small_Images']}}" alt="img3" class="img-thumbnail" [attr.ref]="bigImages['2']['big_Images']">
      <img id="sm003" (mouseenter)="mouseEnter($event)"  src="{{smallImages['3']['small_Images']}}" alt="img4" class="img-thumbnail" [attr.ref]="bigImages['3']['big_Images']">
      <img id="sm004" (mouseenter)="mouseEnter($event)"  src="{{smallImages['4']['small_Images']}}" alt="img5" class="img-thumbnail" [attr.ref]="bigImages['4']['big_Images']">
  </div>
```

Comment: use ``*ngIf='smallImages['0']['small_Images'] ? false : true``

Answer (score 0):

You can use `*ngIf="smallImages['0']['small_Images']"` with `img` tag

```
<img *ngIf="smallImages['0']['small_Images']'" id="sm001" (mouseenter)="mouseEnter($event)"  src="{{smallImages['0']['small_Images']}}" alt="img1" class="img-thumbnail" [attr.ref]="bigImages['0']['big_Images']">
```

Comment: Vivek Doshi , I have changed the image path with your suggestion in as follows it displays alt tag

 <img *ngIf="smallImages['4']['small_Images']" id="sm004" (mouseenter)="mouseEnter($event)"  src="{{smallImages['6']['small_Images']}}" alt="img5" class="img-thumbnail" [attr.ref]="bigImages['6']['big_Images']">


But in API response there is values upto 0 to 4 only .So it should validate the path contains the valid url if it is not a valid on it must disable the img tag .

Comment: I have added just for the first image ,and above below comment you have mixed up multiple the index in single tag , like 4 5 6 , it should be same for all

Comment: 1, For the line five  src="{{smallImages['4']['small_Images']}}" the path of this src is assets/Images/Product_Details_Page/Product_Details_Page_Thumbnails/bal101.png  but which is not a valid path so  the image is not loaded then the alt is displayed..

Comment: 2,I have 5 img tags if my API returns 3 src then the remaining 2 is undefined or empty or null so in that situation I want to show only 3 images .for the remaining 2 I don't want to display anything.

please guide me for achieving this.

Comment: simply when the API response path is not loaded(coz that path is not exists in assets folder Angular4) or the API not returns the path for the specific img tag ,that tag must be get disapled ...this is what I want to do

Comment: But in my case by using the above code ,it displays the alt tag when the API returned path is not gets loaded

Comment: @Nikson , please create a demo on stackblitz.com

Comment: But I can't access the API inside the stackblitz --Vivek Doshi

Comment: @Nikson , then try on other platform , coz I cant help you with this type of conversation , it will be helpful f you can share working demo

Comment: Can you please help me in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49767230/adding-products-in-carousel-generates-new-row-in-angular4